# ArcMap calculate statistics every time I open jp2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, jpeg-2000

I have jp2 raster files, every time i open one of these files ArcMap caluclate the statistics and histogram. Can I stop this
I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1